# setOption startParam works weird in fullcalendar v5

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I was trying to set `startParam` option dynamically.

But it seems working weird by updating the key rather update value.

```
calendarEvents.setOption('startParam', moment().format());
calendarEvents.refetchEvents();
```

If I run the methods and check the form data, then the `startParam` will be look like the following.

```
2021-02-15T19:09:13-07:00: 2021-01-01T00:00:00-07:00
end: 2030-01-01T00:00:00-07:00
```

I guess the `setOption` method updates the key not value for the start params.

Why does this happen and how to fix this?

**UPDATE: My calendar code**

```
calendarEvents = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEventsEl, {
        headerToolbar: false,
        contentHeight: 300,
        initialView: 'listAll',
        views: {
            listAll: {
                type: 'listYear',
                duration: { years: 9 },
            },
        },
        navLinks: false,
        eventDidMount: function (arg) {
            ...
        },
        eventTimeFormat: {
            hour: 'numeric',
            minute: '2-digit',
            meridiem: 'short'
        },
        eventSources: [{
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/calendar/get_all_by_id/' + id,
        }],
        eventSourceSuccess: function(content, xhr) {
            ...

            return events;
        }
    });

    calendarEvents.render();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working properly.

The startParam option sets the name of the parameter which fullCalendar sends to the server for the start value, when fetching events. It doesn't set the value. The value which is sent is always the start date of the range which the user has just navigated to. You don't need to change that value yourself, and anyway it makes no sense to try and give it a fixed value - it is adjusted dynamically by fullCalendar every time events need fetching.

What are you actually trying to achieve with this code? Are you trying to change the current date on the calendar programmatically? If so then use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-gotoDate

Comment: I know how the startParam works. I have a list year mode calendar and it needs to get events with the limitation by re-setting the start params.

Comment: `I know how the startParam works`...then why did you ask the question about what it's doing? What's your real question?

Comment: I have to always show all events within the dates between start and end params.

Comment: `it needs to get events with the limitation by re-setting the start params` ... when re-fetching events, fullCalendar will set the dates automatically depending on the date range showing on the calendar. It's unclear what the actual problem is.

Comment: My calendar doesn't have the `date range` you mentioned, just showing all events from getting events.

Comment: It doesn't define month or week, etc.

Comment: In the question, you showed the dates which fullCalendar is setting for start and end. these are determined by the date range of your view. I can't see the rest of your calendar code, but presumably you must have set a view with a 9 year duration? It would help if you show your calendar code including the view config and the event feed config.

Comment: RIght. Just updated my question adding the code.

Comment: As you can the calendar, it is using type `listYear`, so it gets all events from the current year `2021-01-01...` to `2030-01-01...`, with 9 years of duration. But I need to get events from now on. `2021-02-16T03:45:00-06:00` like this, without hide/show events by handing range or duration, etc. just by getting events.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with getting events from the start of the time period? If you don't want the list to go back to January, then change the duration, or use visibleRange to get more flexibility.

Comment: Ok, it is bad. Why can't I handle startParam and endParam dynamically? And does it update the key rather update value for the params from the beginning?

Comment: I think handling the params is important, because it could improve the speed to get response.

Comment: `Why can't I handle startParam and endParam dynamically`...because the whole point is that it's automatic, and then you don't have to worry about it. If you decided to set a crazy long duration for your view, that's not fullCalendar's fault.

Comment: `And does it update the key rather update value for the params from the beginning` ...I already explained why that happens, in the answer. That option adjusts the **parameter name**, not the parameter value. Did you not understand something? It exists in case you would rather send a different name than `start` or `end` to your server.

Comment: `I think handling the params is important, because it could improve the speed to get response`...as I already explained, the way to do this is to set a different duration for your calendar, possibly by using `visibleRange`. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange . Changing this adjusts the start and end dates of the view. Therefore, when you next refetch the events, it will send different start and end date values to the server.

Comment: Thank you. Btw, the `visibleRange` option can set time as well? It seems that I can set only date.

Comment: No it can only set date. Why do you care about the time, when you have a 9-year view?? It seems petty and insignificant.

Comment: P.S. Consider whether maybe just one year at a time would be enough to show at once in the calendar, or even a few months, or one month. Then the user would use the next/previous buttons to move to a new date range, and that would cause the calendar to fetch more events from the server.